# Java Classpath and relative paths

Tags: java, classpath

If you have a relative path in the java class path, does this just search the current working directory. Does the same hold for class paths declared in a manifest file. In a manifest file is it relative to the dir the jar is in?

Ex.
Cmdline

```
java -cp somejar.jar
```

Or

Manifest

```
Class-Path: somejar.jar
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you say `-cp somejar.jar` you are adding `somejar.jar` to the classpath.  It will only try to find the `somejar.jar` from the directory you are currently in when you typed the command.

If you say in the Manifest

```
Class-Path: somejar.jar
```

you are saying add the jar, `somejar.jar` into the classpath from the directory where the manifest is located(aka inside the jar).

As a side note, when you specify the classpath by using -jar, -cp, or -classpath, you override the system variable CLASSPATH.

More details can be found here, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: It always loads the jar in the manifest classpath from whichever directory the jar is in, even if you launch the jar from the cmdline from a different working dir.

Comment: I'm sorry, isnt that what I said? The manifest is located inside the jar, maybe I should be more clear.

Comment: @greedybuddha, The manifest is in JAR but the referenced second JAR is not searched inside first one. It is searched on file system relatively to the 1st one. So "libs/some.jar" will be searched in sub-directory libs, just below 1st JAR on file system.

Answer (score 6):

You've actually mentioned two different cases:

Case #1

```
java -cp foo/bar/somejar.jar ...
```

In this case the relative path to the JAR (or whatever) is resolved relative to the current directory.

Case #2

```
java -jar foo/bar/somejar.jar ...
```

where somejar.jar contains

```
Class-Path: anotherjar.jar
```

In this case "foo/bar/somejar.jar" is resolved relative to the current directory (as above), but "anotherjar.jar" is resolved relative to the directory containing "somejar.jar".

(Aside: my understanding is that a Manifest Class-Path: attribute is respected when a JAR file is included via `-cp` or `$CLASSPATH`, but it only affects the dependencies of classes loaded from that JAR ... see the "findingclasses" link below.)

References:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html