# Trying to put a java classpath into a jar manifest, not sure which string to use

Tags: java, sqlite, jar, classpath

I have a class anda  jar in a folder. 
sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
dbBuilder.class

To Run dbBuilder.class I run this on command line:

```
java -classpath ".:sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" dbBuilder
```

Now If I want to Jar both these together I create a manifest that looks like this:

```
Main-Class: dbBuilder
Class-Path: sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
```

And I compile it with:

```
jar cfm dbTest.jar Manifest.txt dbBuilder.class sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
```

Then run it:

```
 java -jar dbBuilder.jar
```

And I get this stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.sqlite.JDBC   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)   at
>   dbBuilder.createTables(dbBuilder.java:22)     at
>   dbBuilder.main(dbBuilder.java:67)

I'm confused because the classpath I use to run it when I do it without a jar is different then the classpath I put in the manifest but I tried using the class path I use to run it as a class and putting it in the manifest and that didn't work either. So I'm not sure how to get it to compile, also follow up- Once I have this dbBuilder.jar working, would I be able to jar that again and still access sqlite classes ? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I mentioned above they are in the same directory.. your saying the way I'm doing it right now should be correct though ?

Comment: Is there any solution for this issue? i am having the same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The JAR documentation says this:

> *"Class-Path: The value of this attribute specifies the relative URLs of the extensions or libraries that this application or extension needs. URLs are separated by one or more spaces. The application or extension class loader uses the value of this attribute to construct its internal search path."*

If the relative URLs have a relative path, they will be resolved relative to the directory containing the main JAR file.  (Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502944/139985)

In your example, that means that `dbTest.jar` and `sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar` would need to be in the same directory.  I expect that's what you have got wrong here.